# Microsoft Teams - pymsteams

Tags: python, pycharm, office365, microsoft-teams

I have a team of 14 people who I constantly have to remind of multiple things through out the day, which is why I want to automate most of my messages.

I went ahead and wrote a script to send a simple message to one of our channels in Microsoft Team, also connected it with WebHook.

So far it seems to work if I run the script manually from PyCharm:

```
import pymsteams
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("webhookconnectioncodegoeshere")
myTeamsMessage.text(": test ;)")
myTeamsMessage.send()
```

=======================================================================

I am having trouble automating this script, I tried to schedule it from within Task Manager in Win10 but the script does not run, all it does it opens the script in Pycharm but if i run the script manually from within Pycharm is send the message.

Appreciate your input.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have Power Automate (formerly Flow)? It works really well for these types of situations, then you don't need to host your script anywhere. Checkout: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_teams/microsoft-teams/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, would comment if I could.

Another option is to use google cloud to run your python script and other hosting websites, check out:
https://cloud.google.com/python